# Append #label with links to scroll the page in django templates

Tags: python, django

I am populating a link using below line.

```
<a role="button" href="{% url 'home:explore' %}">Contact Us</a>
```

I need to append an html elements id with the link so that it will scroll to that location when the page opens. I tried adding the #label in the href as below. But, this adds an extra / before the #label.

```
<a role="button" href="{% url 'home:explore' %}#contactus">Contact Us</a>
```

Resulting link: home/explore/#contactus

How to do this without adding the / after explore like this:

/home/explore#contactus

Comment: It will work either way. I was just confused. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work either way.

```
<a role="button" href="{% url 'home:explore' %}#contactus">Contact Us</a>
```

This will generate the url: home/explore/#contactus

and to my surprise, that url worked just like home/explore#contactus as in normal html even though it confuses us first! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's problem in your url regex, you hardcoded trailing slash in regex and url tag added trailing slash as well. You can try to add `?` after trailing slash in your url pattern, or completely remove this slash.